# If a set K $\subseteq \mathbb{R} $ is closed and bounded, it is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

If a sequence is closed and bounded, that means it has a sequence that converges. According to the Bolzano-Weierstrauss Theorem (which I am taking for granted), a converging sequence has subsequences that converge to the same limit. By definition of compactness, every sequence in K has a subsequence that converges to a limit that is also in K. Therefore, if a set is closed and bounded, it is compact.

Is this correct, or should I add more to it?

Comment: Well technically the definition of compactness you use is only of sequential compactness, not of "true" (topological) compactness, but the two notions coincide for metric spaces (I believe) so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Yes, your work is correct if you can simply take the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem for granted.  However, it is worth noting that this theorem is essentially the same as stating that $\Bbb R$ has this property

Comment: For your more information, in a complete metric space a set is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded. If the metric space is incomplete, then compactness implies closed and bounded, but converse may not be true.

Comment: @B.R.Datt. No. Even a locally compact complete metic space may have a closed bounded non-compact subset.  For example on $\mathbb R$ , let $d(x,y)=\min (1,|x-y|).$ Then every subset of $\mathbb R$ is bounded, and $\mathbb Z$ is closed but not compact.

Answer (score 1):

A metric space is compact iff it is complete and totally bounded. Bounded sets in $\mathbb R$ are totally bounded, as if $\sup\{|x|:x\in K\}=M<\infty$, then $K\subset[-M,M]$ and for any $\varepsilon>0$, we may cover $[-M,M]$ with the finite collection of open intervals $$(-M-\varepsilon,-M+\varepsilon), \left((-M+\frac\varepsilon2)-\varepsilon,(-M+\frac\varepsilon2)+\varepsilon\right),\ldots, (M-\varepsilon,M+\varepsilon). $$ $K$ is complete as if $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $K$, it has a limit $x\in \mathbb R$, and since $K$ is closed, $x\in K$. It follows that $K$ is compact.